# Git Private repository access

Tags: git, github

I need to access the private git repository. I got the private OpenSSH key, then converted it to public key and added it to my git profile. Now when I enter the URL to that repository into search bar I still get an 404 page not found.

I tried googling solution but as I am new to git I couldn’t get the idea from there. Maybe someone here can help me?

Comment: Is that a repository that you created all by yourself?

Comment: Did you try to [make the repository public](https://help.github.jp/enterprise/2.11/user/articles/making-a-private-repository-public) after logging into GitHub?

Comment: No, it is someone elses repo... I got the private openssh key which i suppose should turn into public key and add it to my keys and just open repo URI in web.